# Iterating in a with_items loop ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

Hi there i am atm trying to get the hang of ansible with aws and i am really likeing the flexibility of it so far.

Sadly now i am starting to hit a brick wall with my experiments. I am trying to tag volumes for specific instances that have the tag ***environment: test*** with the tages **environment: test** and **backup: true** . The playbook is working as intended if i specify every single Index of the array in the with_items loop. Here's my playbook so far:

```
---
- name: Tag the EBS Volumes
  hosts: tag_environment_test
  gather_facts: False
  tags: tag
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/vars/aws.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Gather instance instance_ids
    local_action:
        module: ec2_remote_facts
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        filters:
            instance-state-name: running
            "tag:environment": test
    register: test_id

  - name: Gather volume information for instance
    local_action:
        module: ec2_vol
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        instance: "{{ item.id }}"
        state: list
    with_items:
     - "{{ test_id.instances }}"
    register:  ec2_volumes
  - debug:
      var: ec2_volumes

  - name: Do some actual tagging
    local_action:
       module: ec2_tag
       region: '{{ aws_region }}'
       resource: "{{ item.id }}"
       args:
         tags:
          environment: test
          backup: true
    with_items:
      - "{{ ec2_volumes.results[0].volumes }}"
#      - "{{ ec2_volumes.results[1].volumes }}"
```

My question now is it possible to iterate over the full array in ec2_volumes.results without having the need to specify every single value in the array. Like for example **_ec2_volumes.results[X].volumes X=X+1_** so every time he goes through the loop he iterates +1 until the end of the array.

Every Input also on the rest of the playbook would be very appriciated (like i said still trying to get the hang of ansible. :)

Greeting 
Drees

Comment: What does the content of `ec2_volumes.results` look like? Please update your question with the output of `debug: var=ec2_volums.results`.

Comment: ec2_volumes.results actually gives all data regarding the ec2_instances that have afformentioned tags. ec2_volumes.results[0].volumes returns the volume of the first instance. I can address the other instances with ec2_volumes.results[1].volumes and so on. Posting the output would take a lot of effort since it contains a lot of sensible data which i would need to edit out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your list of results:

```
- name: Do some actual tagging
  delegate_to: localhost
  ec2_tag:
    region: '{{ aws_region }}'
    resource: "{{ item.volume.id }}"
    tags:
      environment: test
      backup: true
  with_items: "{{ ec2_volumes.results }}"
```

---

> Every Input also on the rest of the playbook would be very appreciated

Consider using `delegate_to: localhost` instead of `local_action`.  Consider this task:

```
- name: an example
  command: do something
```

Using `delegate_to`, I only need to add a single line:

```
- name: an example
  delegate_to: localhost
  command: do something
```

Whereas using `local_action` I need to rewrite the task:

```
- name: an example
  local_action:
    module: command do something
```

And of course, `delegate_to` is more flexible: you can use it to delegate to hosts other than localhost.

**Update**

Without seeing your actual playbook it's hard to identify the source of the error.  Here's a complete playbook that runs successfully (using synthesized data and wrapping your `ec2_tag` task in a `debug` task):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    aws_region: example
    ec2_volumes:
      results:
        - volume:
            id: 1
        - volume:
            id: 2
  tasks:
    - name: Do some actual tagging
      debug:
        msg:
          ec2_tag:
            region: '{{ aws_region }}'
            resource: '{{ item.volume.id }}'
            tags:
              environment: test
              backup: true
      with_items: "{{ ec2_volumes.results }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input i will use delegate_to from now on it seems way more comfortable. Sadly i now get an error when i try your changes: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/add_volume_tag.yml'`

Comment: I ended up mis-indenting things when cleaning up your task.  I've fixed up the indenting here in the answer, and included a complete test playbook.

Comment: What do you mean by actual playbook? Do you mean the debug informations? Sorry if my questions seem stupid like i said just starting out with ansible. I included my actually working playbook. I will try to include the output of the debug message. Just gonna take a while.

Comment: What? I didn't say anything about an "actual playbook".  I said I included a complete test playbook in my answer, so that you can run it and verify that it does what you want.

Comment: Without seeing your actual playbook it's hard to identify the source of the error. Sorry if i missinterpreted this sentence. They playbook nearly does what i want but it still has a fixed set volumes . What i want to do is tag the volumes of X numbers of instances each with one volume attached to them.

Comment: This shows how to iterate over "the full array in ec2_volumes.results". Not sure what else you're looking for, sorry.

Comment: Yes your playbook works if i only got 2 values in my array but what for example if the value of X = 30 or whatever. It shouldn't work then or do i get something wrong there?

Comment: There is nothing in this playbook that is limited to 2 values. Sure, my sample data only has two values in it, but if you were to use your actual data with the same tasks they would work for a list of any length.

Comment: I finally got it i had to put the volumes into the resource field not into the with_items field. Thanks your input helped me alot in finding the solution.